# loadjava NullPointerException when trying to load

Tags: oracle11g, nullpointerexception, loadjava

i am trying to use the loadjava utility in an oracle 11g database, i have all the proper privs, yet i am getting this error:

The command:

```
c:\load>loadjava -user ccar_eccar/ccar_eccar@ccar -thin tsakirisd-hp:1521:ccar -verbose *.jar
```

The output(since I am not writing to a logfile). You can see it picks up all the jar files I need to load into my DB:

`arguments: '-user' 'ccar_eccar/***@ccar' '-thin' 'tsakirisd-hp:1521:ccar' '-verbose' 'activation-1.1.1.jar' 'axis-ant.jar' 'axis.jar' 'bcprov-ext-jdk14-145.jar' 'bcprov-jdk14-145.jar' 'ccar_eccar_interface_11g.jar' 'commons-discovery-0.2.jar' 'commons-logging-1.0.4.jar' 'jaxrpc.jar' 'log4j-1.2.8.jar' 'mail.jar' 'opensaml.jar' 'saaj.jar' 'wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar' 'wss4j-1.5.2.jar' 'xalan-2.4.1.jar' 'xercesImpl.jar' 'xercesSamples.jar' 'xmlParserAPIs.jar' 'xmlsec-1.4.1.jar'`

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.add(LoadJava.java:724)
>     at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.processDeferredFiles(LoadJava.java:641)
>     at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.process(LoadJava.java:995)
>     at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJava.command(LoadJava.java:278)
>     at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.run(LoadJavaMain.java:179)
>     at oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain.main(LoadJavaMain.java:64)

Seems to blow up in the add. I researched all over, yet I cannot seems to figure out why this will not work.

thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue in the past in a scenario where a developer was running Oracle 64 bit server, and had a 32 bit Oracle Client installed (or vice versa). Try it without the -thin and then check your logfile, You may see a warning like

> Error while connecting with oci8 driver: oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.ToolsException: 
>   The JDBC OCI8 Driver is not installed properly, Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

If you do see that error, try installing the instant client version that matches your server version, and try again.